# MySQL - Count Rows between two values in a Column repeatedly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so

```
id  | status  |  data  | date
----|---------|--------|-------
  1 | START   |  a4c   | Jan 1
  2 | WORKING |  2w3   | Dec 29
  3 | WORKING |  2d3   | Dec 29
  4 | WORKING |  3ew   | Dec 26
  5 | WORKING |  5r5   | Dec 23
  6 | START   |  2q3   | Dec 22
  7 | WORKING |  32w   | Dec 20
  8 | WORKING |  9k5   | Dec 10

and so on...
```

What I am trying to do, is to get the number of 'WORKING' rows between two 'START' i.e.

```
id  | status  |  count | date
----|---------|--------|-------
  1 | START   |  4     | Jan 1
  6 | START   |  2     | Dec 22

and so on ...
```

I am using MySql 5.7.28.

Highly appreciate any help/suggestion!

Comment: Do you really have dates in that format are are they proper dates?

Comment: *get the number of 'WORKING' rows between two 'START'* The task needs in some ordering usage. Does the ordering by `id` is safe?

Comment: What two START are rows 6 and 7 between?

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for the reply. Currently, I am storing date in day only format, but I can add a column or change the current date column to store date in Unix timestamp or MySQL timestamp format.

Comment: @ Akina : Thanks for the reply. The id is Auto Increment Primary Key for the table, so I believe it's unique and incrementing.

Comment: @Straberry : Thanks for the reply. Every START row denotes the start of an activity/work. It also means the previous (if any) activity has completed.

Answer (score 0):

`date` is unusable in the example, try using `id` as an ordering column instead

```
select id, status, 
  (select count(*) 
   from mytable t2 
   where t2.id > t.id and t2.status='WORKING' 
      and not exists (select 1 
                      from mytable t3 
                      where t3.id > t.id and t3.id < t2.id and status='START')
  ) count,
  date
from mytable t
where  status='START';
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1036f311805b099da11504328869a481)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am storing the data in day only format to do a group by easier. But if it makes the logic easier on counting the rows for each start, I can store the date in a timestamp as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming id is safe then you can do this by finding the next id for each block (and assigning some dummy values) then grouping by next id

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int,status  varchar(20),  data varchar(3),date varchar(10));
insert into t values
(  1 , 'START'   ,  'a4c'   , 'Jan 1'),
(  2 , 'WORKING' ,  '2w3'   , 'Dec 29'),
(  3 , 'WORKING' ,  '2d3'   , 'Dec 29'),
(  4 , 'WORKING' ,  '3ew'   , 'Dec 26'),
(  5 , 'WORKING' ,  '5r5'   , 'Dec 23'),
(  6 , 'START'   ,  '2q3'   , 'Dec 22'),
(  7 , 'WORKING' ,  '32w'   , 'Dec 20'),
(  8 , 'WORKING' ,  '9k5'   , 'Dec 10');

SELECT  MIN(ID) ID,
            'START' STATUS,
            SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS <> 'START' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OBS,
            Max(DATE) DATE
FROM
(
select t.*,
        CASE WHEN STATUS = 'START' THEN DATE ELSE '' END AS DT,
        COALESCE(
        (select t1.id from t t1 where t1.STATUS = 'START' and t1.id > t.id ORDER BY T1.ID limit 1) 
        ,99999) NEXTID
from t
) S 
GROUP BY NEXTID;    
+------+--------+------+--------+
| ID   | STATUS | OBS  | DATE   |
+------+--------+------+--------+
|    1 | START  |    4 | Jan 1  |
|    6 | START  |    2 | Dec 22 |
+------+--------+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks P.Salmon. Let me try this solution. Will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT id, status, `count`, `date`
FROM ( SELECT @count `count`,
              id,
              status,
              `date`,
              @count:=(@status=status)*@count+1, 
              @status:=status
       FROM test, 
            ( SELECT @count:=0, @status:='' ) init_vars
       ORDER BY id DESC
     ) calculations
WHERE status='START'
ORDER BY id
```

> > Since I am still in design/development I can move to MySQL 8 if that makes it easier for this logic? Any idea how this could be done with Windows functions? – N0000B

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id,
                     status,
                     `date`,
                     SUM(status='WORKING') OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) workings
              FROM test
              ORDER BY id )
SELECT id, 
       status, 
       workings - COALESCE(LEAD(workings) OVER (ORDER BY id), 0) `count`,
       `date`
FROM cte
WHERE status='START'
ORDER BY id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce4a39a599e80c68b200c6f5427f9dbd)

Comment: Could this be simplified?

Comment: @Strawberry I don't understand your question. What do you want to simplify? It is absolutely simple and clear now - if somebody cannot understand then he may execute the subquery `calculations` only and investigate its result.

Comment: Thanks Akina, I'll try out your solution & get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands problem -- which is simpler in MySQL 8+ using window functions.

In older versions, probably the most efficient method is to accumulate a count of starts to define groupings for the rows.  You can do this using variables and then aggregate:

```
select min(id) as id, 'START' as status, sum(status = 'WORKING') as num_working, max(date) as date
from (select t.*, (@s := @s + (t.status = 'START')) as grp
      from (select t.* from t order by id asc) t cross join
           (select @s := 0) params
     ) t
group by grp
order by min(id);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a7f3c7a5d98709e9eda0ae736c1a51e8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try it out. Since I am still in design/development I can move to MySQL 8 if that makes it easier for this logic? Any idea how this could be done with Windows functions?

Comment: @N0000B . . . This question is clearly about pre-MySQL 8+.  Ask another question for an 8+ solution.